# На каком языке пишут программы для чипов, которые впаяны в плату?

Tags: c

Многие детские игрушки, и не только, к примеру калькулятор, имеют на плате чип. А на каком языке они это программируют?

Comment: это делают на разных языках. зачем вам это нужно знать?

Comment: Бывают специализированные контроллеры, когда вся логика реализована прямо в железе (самый простой пример — электронные часы).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для программирования микроконтроллеров чаще всего используют ассемблер и C.

Comment: А как микроконтроллер понимает язык?

Comment: Программа компилируется в машинный код, который впоследтсвии переводится в двоичный, двоичный код служет инструкцией для операций над ячейками памяти.  На самом деле для микрокотроллеров можно много других языков использовать, преимущество ассемблера - его близось к железу.

Comment: @Sergiyss микроконтроллеры и "чипы" это могут быть разные вещи ... А саму электронику, т.е. те самые "чипы" разрабатывают в основном на VHDL

Comment: @Sergiyss, дополню: сначала программа на исходном языке преобразуется в файл прошивки, который затем копируется в ППЗУ микросхемы с помощью программатора.